# how to make an image appear everytime when i shake my iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created a shake application in iphone but i am having a problem. I want that when i shake my iphone everytime an image should appear for every shake.Can anybody help how is it possible.
This is the code which i have written:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(110.0f, 70.0f, 220.0f, 380.0f);
//This line is for setting my tick.png image on my image view
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
            [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_mark.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:myImage];

       //animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
                [myImage setAlpha:0.0];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

        [myImage release];
```

This is for beginning animations and I have set my image alpha to 0.0 so that my image will disappear.  This code is working properly.  But I want it so that when I shake my iPhone again my image should reappear for every shake. How is it possible.

Comment: pls format your code properly. its hard to read

Comment: .. did you try the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use UIAccelerometer for this purpose,Use the following code

```
@interface PageLoopViewController : UIViewController<UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
UIAccelerationValue myAccelerometer[3];
}
******************* .m code*********************

#define kAccelerometerFrequency  10 //Hz
#define kFilteringFactor     0.5
#define kEraseAccelerationThreshold 0.2 

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];


[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(1.30 / kAccelerometerFrequency)];

}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration
{
UIAccelerationValue  length, x, y,z;


//Use a basic high-pass filter to remove the influence of the gravity
myAccelerometer[0] = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[0] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
myAccelerometer[1] = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[1] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
myAccelerometer[2] = acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[2] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
// Compute values for the three axes of the acceleromater
x = acceleration.x - myAccelerometer[0];
y = acceleration.y - myAccelerometer[1];
z = acceleration.z - myAccelerometer[2];

//Compute the intensity of the current acceleration 
length = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
if(length > kEraseAccelerationThreshold)
{
    //Image code            

}

}
```

Cheers

Comment: hi i try but it's not working properly it is giving me an error that invalid binary operator where i compute values using addition and subtraction i.e + and - .Please help me in solving this problem

Comment: myAccelerometer[0] = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[0] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
myAccelerometer[1] = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[1] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
myAccelerometer[2] = acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor + myAccelerometer[2] * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);  1st i got an error that myAccelerometer is undeclared than i created declared myAccrelometer and after 1 got an in the above three lines that invalid binary operators. i think in objective-c (+) and (-) operators are not used .Please help me how to solve the problem

Comment: else if ( fabs(acceleration.x) >mAccelerationThresold || fabs( acceleration.y) >mAccelerationThresold || fabs(acceleration.z) >mAccelerationThresold ){
  ShakingCount ++;
  if (ShakingCount > mShakecount )
  {
   CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(110.0f, 70.0f, 220.0f, 380.0f);
 UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
   [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_mark.png"]];
  [self.view addSubview:myImage];
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [myImage setAlpha:0.0];
 [UIView commitAnimations]; 
[myImage release];

Comment: Implement the UIAcclerometerDelegate in your header file and declare myAccelerometer as UIAccelerationValue myAccelerometer[3]; in the header file.

Comment: this code working properly but for one time not in every shake  how i try in every shake